# syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW inside class method

Tags: php

Have been stuck with this little issue, when using key value arrays inside a class |I will get an `error syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'`

```
class hello{

  public function name(){

    $allnames = array("name"=>"mark" , "role" => "admin");

  }

}
```

Comment: The example code just works as is

Comment: this works perfectly fine. Please post the actual code and not just a sample.

Comment: Your question is Unclear and not useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code in my system there is no any error in your code

```
<?php
class hello{

  public function name(){

    $allnames = array("name"=>"mark" , "role" => "admin");
    return $allnames;
  }

}

$obj = new hello;
print_r($obj->name())

?>
```

Please check

You may try assign array as

```
$allnames = ["name"=>"mark" , "role" => "admin"];
```

Comment: Yes this is working, so not sure why my code isn't...